# Git repository for a group in a server without admin rights

Tags: linux, git

I have a project which our research lab is working, but only a few members can have access to the codes. We are using Git and BitBucket, but we want to use the server lab as our main repository. I have the following constraints:

- We don't have admin rights;
- Only a few members can have access to the files;
- Every lab member already has its own login in the server.

How can I make this work?

I was thinking to ask the admin to add a group in the server, which would have read/write rights in our Git repository folder. Does it work? Is there a better way to manage these Git repositories with these constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Borealid wrote in his answer, you could also use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/). It allows you to have much more fine-grained access control (e.g. you can prevent users from deleting your repositories or prevent (some of) them from pushing to certain branches). It doesn't require root access.

Comment: So, I can use gitolite inside my login, managing which users in the server can have access to the files? But, if the repository is inside my home folder, they can have access to the repository without having access to my home folder?

Comment: @VictorHugo: You can remove group/world read or execute permission on the repository folder. Gitolite runs under your uid, so it can still write to them.

Comment: ressurecting the topic :-) how does users that doesn't have a login in my server can connect to my repository?

Comment: Problem solved. [A helpful guide](http://www.mmncs.com/2011/07/how-to-install-and-setup-a-git-repository-server-using-gitolite-on-linux-ubuntu-11-04-server-and-client/).

Answer (score 2):

Having a POSIX group which is granted access to the repository directory is a fine way to do things.

Just be aware that you have to trust the other group members - they could delete the directory entirely, without using the git client.

Comment: It's one of the things I'm concerned about. I'm new to Git and recently lost some codes. Fortunately, I had a backup. So, what I'm thinking is to use the POSIX group and do backup in the cloud, like BitBucket for example.